# Split string Ruby on Rails based on number of characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to split these numbers

```
a = 900000 
b = 1800000 
c = 5000
```

into these

> a[0] = 900
>
> a[1] = 000
>
> b[0] = 1800
>
> b[1] = 000
>
> c[0] = 5
>
> c[1] = 000

How can I possibly do this?

Comment: Why is 1800 not split into 1 and 800?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with range:

```
a = 1800000 
[a.to_s[0...-3], a.to_s[-3..-1]]
# => ["1800", "000"]
```

Using [`Numeric#divmod`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod)

```
a.divmod(1000)
# => [1800, 0]
a.divmod(1000).map { |n| '%03d' % n }
# => ["1800", "000"]
```

Using regular expression:

```
a.to_s.match(/(.*)(.{3})$/).captures
# => ["1800", "000"]
```

Comment: The question seem to imply that it want's to split trailing zeros in sets of 3. The first and third method will split any digits?

Comment: @rickypai, All (including the second) will split any digits.

Comment: @rickypai, In case OP want split trailing zero, OP can use the 3rd method slightly modified: `a.to_s.match(/(.*)(000)$/).captures`

Comment: Wow, no less than three methods? +3 if I could. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
b.to_s.chars[0..-4].join
```

and

```
b.to_s.chars.last(3).join
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the source code from rails NumberHelper's number_with_delimiter method

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 263
def number_with_delimiter(number, options = {})
  options.symbolize_keys!

  options[:delimiter] = ERB::Util.html_escape(options[:delimiter]) if options[:delimiter]
  options[:separator] = ERB::Util.html_escape(options[:separator]) if options[:separator]

  begin
    Float(number)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    if options[:raise]
      raise InvalidNumberError, number
    else
      return number
    end
  end

  defaults = I18n.translate(:'number.format', :locale => options[:locale], :default => {})
  options = options.reverse_merge(defaults)

  parts = number.to_s.to_str.split('.')
  parts[0].gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{options[:delimiter]}")
  parts.join(options[:separator]).html_safe
end
```

and i think the code you looks for is this one

```
parts[0].gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{options[:delimiter]}")
```